# NoMethodError in SessionsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok, I'm learning R on R from the Pragmatic Bookshelf text *Agile Webdevelopment with Rails 4th ed.*

I'm at page 212 and I'm getting this error....`NoMethodError in SessionsController#create` and `app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:7:in 'create'`

I'm pulling my beard out over here, I've spent days trying to track this down. Here is the create code this is pointing to...

```
def create
  if user = User.authenticate(params[:name], params[:password])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to admin_url
  else
    redirect_to login_url, :alert => "Invalid user/password combination"
  end
end
```

Can any Guru out there assist?

Comment: did you define `authenticate` in the User model?

Comment: What is line 7? What method does it claim to be missing?

Comment: Ok...after taking a break I noticed I misnamed the User.authenticate in my model. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need the following in your user model (page 203 on my book.)  If that is not the issue, please provide your user model too.

```
def User.authenticate(name, password)
  if user = find_by_name(name)
    if user.hashed_password == encrypt_password(password, user.salt)
      user
    end
  end
end
```